# Is $a\cdot (-1)^a$ monotonic?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I'm having difficulty understanding what is a monotonic sequence? Is this Monotonic? This is because that this function doesn't increase or decrease with consistency. Also does $\dfrac{(-1)^a}{a}$ have a limit? No right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is some ambiguity in the term *monotonic*.

For example, with respect to the phrase "monotonically increasing",
at least one mathSE reviewer that I have exchanged comments with regards this as synonomous with "strictly increasing".

Alternatively, I have seen old math books that regard "monotonically increasing" as synonymous with "non-decreasing."

Consider (for example) the sequence

$$ (1 \times [-1]^1), ~(2 \times [-1]^2), ~(3 \times [-1]^3) \cdots$$

The even #'d terms are positive and the odd #'d terms are negative.  Therefore, the sequence is *bouncing back and forth* between greater than zero and less than zero.

Therefore, under **any** definition of *monotonic*, the sequence is not monontonic.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** monotonic. You need your sequence to obey $a_n\leq a_{n+1}$ **for every** $n$ or $a_{n+1}\leq a_n.$ If $a_n = n\cdot (-1)^n,$ then $a_{2n-1}\leq a_{2n}\geq a_{2n+1}.$ So there is no consistency in the inequality.
That sequence $(-1)^n/n$ actually converges to $0$ because for $n$ big enough you will find $(-1)^n/n$ as closed as you want to $0.$ This words explain the definition of **limit** as the $\epsilon -\delta$ arguments.